# App crashes when Bluetooth permission is allowed but works fine when denied while testing the android app

Tags: android, kotlin

When testing the app, **if the Bluetooth is off**, when clicked connect button the app asks for permission to allow Bluetooth. When allowed the app crashes saying "isn't Responding", but when denied it shows a toast saying Bluetooth is not enabled as expected

this is the mainActivity.kt :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
private lateinit var bluetoothSocket: BluetoothSocket

private val requestEnableBluetoothLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        connectToBluetoothDevice()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    //different slider controlled by servo motors
    val waistSlider = findViewById<RangeSlider>(R.id.waistSlider)!!
    val shoulderSlider = findViewById<RangeSlider>(R.id.shoulderSlider)!!
    val elbowSlider: RangeSlider = findViewById<RangeSlider>(R.id.elbowSlider)
    val wristRollSlider: RangeSlider = findViewById<RangeSlider>(R.id.wristRollSlider)
    val wristPitchSlider: RangeSlider = findViewById<RangeSlider>(R.id.wristPitchSlider)
    val gripSlider: RangeSlider = findViewById<RangeSlider>(R.id.gripSlider)


    val saveButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.Save)
    val connectButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.connectBtn)
    val disconnectButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.disconnectBtn)

    //initialize bluetooth adapter
    val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
    bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter()

    connectButton.setOnClickListener {
        if (isBluetoothEnabled()) {
            connectToBluetoothDevice()
        } else {
            requestEnableBluetooth()
        }
    }

    //popup message if bluetooth is off
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null || !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return
    }

    //enable bluetooth if not
    if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
        val enableBluetoothIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
        requestEnableBluetoothLauncher.launch(enableBluetoothIntent)
    }
    else {
       connectToBluetoothDevice()
    }
    //Set up Range Slidera
    waistSlider.addOnChangeListener { slider, value, fromUser ->
        val position = value.toInt()
        sendServoPosition("s1", position)
    }
    shoulderSlider.addOnChangeListener { slider, value, fromUser ->
        val position = value.toInt()
        sendServoPosition("s2", position)
    }
    elbowSlider.addOnChangeListener { slider, value, fromUser ->
        val position = value.toInt()
        sendServoPosition("s3", position)
    }
    wristRollSlider.addOnChangeListener { slider, value, fromUser ->
        val position = value.toInt()
        sendServoPosition("s4", position)
    }
    wristPitchSlider.addOnChangeListener { slider, value, fromUser ->
        val position = value.toInt()
        sendServoPosition("s5", position)
    }
    gripSlider.addOnChangeListener { slider, value, fromUser ->
        val position = value.toInt()
        sendServoPosition("s6", position)
    }

    saveButton.setOnClickListener {
        sendServoPosition("SAVE", 0) // Send "SAVE" command to Arduino
    }

    disconnectButton.setOnClickListener {
        disconnectBluetoothDevice()
    }
}
private fun isBluetoothEnabled(): Boolean {
    return bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled
}

private fun requestEnableBluetooth() {
    val enableBluetoothIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
    requestEnableBluetoothLauncher.launch(enableBluetoothIntent)
}

private fun sendServoPosition(servoNumber: String, position: Int) {
    val outputStream: OutputStream
    try {
        if (servoNumber == "SAVE") {
            val message = servoNumber // Only send the command without position for saving
            val bytes = message.encodeToByteArray()
            outputStream = bluetoothSocket.outputStream
            outputStream.write(bytes)
        } else {
            val message = "$servoNumber:$position" // Format the message to include servo number and position
            val bytes = message.encodeToByteArray()
            outputStream = bluetoothSocket.outputStream
            outputStream.write(bytes)
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to send position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

private fun connectToBluetoothDevice() {
        // Get the Bluetooth device with HC-05's MAC address
        val device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(HC05_MAC_ADDRESS)
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT),
                    REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH
                )
                return
            }
    // Check if the Bluetooth device is available
    if (device == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth device not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return
    }

    // Create a Bluetooth socket
        try {
            bluetoothSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID)
            bluetoothSocket.connect()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connected to HC-05", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            // Start sending/receiving data through the Bluetooth connection
            // You can use the input/output streams of the Bluetooth socket to send/receive data
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to connect to HC-05", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    val device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(HC05_MAC_ADDRESS)

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH) {
        if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // The permission was granted, so you can connect to the Bluetooth device
            try {
                connectToBluetoothDevice()
            } catch (e:IOException) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        } else {
            // The permission was denied, so you cannot connect to the Bluetooth device
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

private fun disconnectBluetoothDevice() {
    try {
        bluetoothSocket.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    // Close the Bluetooth socket when the activity is destroyed
    try {
        bluetoothSocket.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
companion object {
    private const val REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1
    private const val HC05_MAC_ADDRESS = "00:00:00:00:00:00" // Replace with your HC-05 MAC address
    private val MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB") // Standard UUID for SPP
} }
```

here's the Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

i am unable to understand why the app is crashing and sometimes it just randomly crashes.

here's the logcat: (after i clicked connect button allowed Bluetooth permission)

```
023-06-20 00:00:40.579  9112-9137  EGL_emulation           com.example.rawis                    D  app_time_stats: avg=911.33ms min=14.95ms max=5337.36ms count=6
2023-06-20 00:00:41.556  9112-9134  BluetoothAdapter        com.example.rawis                    D  onBluetoothServiceDown
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (9112) for package com.example.rawis ----------------------------
2023-06-20 00:00:46.064  9112-9137  EGL_emulation           com.example.rawis                    D  app_time_stats: avg=1366.52ms min=24.56ms max=5382.63ms count=4
2023-06-20 00:00:51.133  9112-9132  BluetoothAdapter        com.example.rawis                    D  onBluetoothServiceUp: android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@f1a08f6
2023-06-20 00:00:53.316  9112-9112  Compatibil...geReporter com.example.rawis                    D  Compat change id reported: 78294732; UID 10172; state: ENABLED
2023-06-20 00:00:59.396  9112-9121  m.example.rawis         com.example.rawis                    I  Thread[6,tid=9121,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x7fd89d4b6f50,peer=0x132801f8,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
2023-06-20 00:00:59.396  9112-9121  m.example.rawis         com.example.rawis                    I  
2023-06-20 00:00:59.694  9112-9121  m.example.rawis         com.example.rawis                    I  Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
2023-06-20 00:01:05.068   680-9398  ActivityManager         system_process                       E  ANR in com.example.rawis (com.example.rawis/.MainActivity)
                                                                                                    PID: 9112
                                                                                                    Reason: Input dispatching timed out (6d7eb94 com.example.rawis/com.example.rawis.MainActivity (server) is not responding. Waited 5004ms for FocusEvent(hasFocus=true))
                                                                                                    Parent: com.example.rawis/.MainActivity
                                                                                                    ErrorId: a870c4c6-0e5a-405b-8065-d4bf3710d6d7
                                                                                                    Frozen: false
                                                                                                    Load: 2.31 / 0.69 / 0.98
                                                                                                    ----- Output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
                                                                                                    some avg10=8.35 avg60=3.04 avg300=0.97 total=60396372
                                                                                                    full avg10=6.50 avg60=2.25 avg300=0.73 total=34681555
                                                                                                    ----- End output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    CPU usage from 0ms to 6387ms later (2023-06-20 00:00:58.665 to 2023-06-20 00:01:05.052):
                                                                                                      27% 680/system_server: 4.2% user + 23% kernel / faults: 1913 minor 150 major
                                                                                                      12% 142/kswapd0: 0% user + 12% kernel
                                                                                                      11% 7373/com.google.android.youtube: 10% user + 1.5% kernel / faults: 1460 minor 48 major
                                                                                                      7.9% 896/com.android.systemui: 1.4% user + 6.5% kernel / faults: 1173 minor 172 major
                                                                                                      0% 2078/com.android.emulator.multidisplay: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 216 minor 31 major
                                                                                                      4.6% 1315/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher: 1.7% user + 2.9% kernel / faults: 915 minor 217 major
                                                                                                      4% 1118/com.android.phone: 2.6% user + 1.4% kernel / faults: 249 minor 24 major
                                                                                                      0% 1060/com.android.se: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 169 minor 1 major
                                                                                                      3.2% 9112/com.example.rawis: 0.6% user + 2.6% kernel / faults: 941 minor 63 major
                                                                                                      3.1% 517/adbd: 0.3% user + 2.8% kernel / faults: 1272 minor
                                                                                                      1% 9133/kworker/u12:4-phy1: 0% user + 1% kernel
                                                                                                      3.1% 9280/com.android.bluetooth: 0.7% user + 2.3% kernel / faults: 750 minor 18 major
                                                                                                      2.8% 995/com.android.networkstack.process: 2.1% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 184 minor 7 major
                                                                                                      2.6% 9059/kworker/u12:2-kverityd: 0% user + 2.6% kernel
                                                                                                      2.1% 9/kworker/u12:1-kverityd: 0% user + 2.1% kernel
                                                                                                      1.7% 262/logd: 0.1% user + 1.5% kernel / faults: 12 minor 1 major
                                                                                                      1.5% 1/init: 0% user + 1.5% kernel / faults: 1 major
                                                                                                      1.5% 84/kworker/3:1-events: 0% user + 1.5% kernel
                                                                                                      1.5% 457/android.hardware.sensors@2.1-service.multihal: 0% user + 1.5% kernel
                                                                                                      0% 588/media.swcodec: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2126 minor 18 major
                                                                                                      1.2% 502/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 1.2% kernel / faults: 118 minor
                                                                                                      1.2% 551/logcat: 0.3% user + 0.9% kernel
                                                                                                      1% 440/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.4-service: 0% user + 1% kernel
                                                                                                      0.9% 494/audioserver: 0% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 91 minor
                                                                                                      0.4% 554/cameraserver: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 97 minor 12 major
                                                                                                      0% 316/tombstoned: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 major
                                                                                                      0% 569/media.extractor: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1159 minor 1 major
                                                                                                      0% 578/mediaserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 48 minor 30 major
                                                                                                      0.7% 4312/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0.1% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 15 minor
                                                                                                      0.2% 12/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                                                                      0.6% 36/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
                                                                                                      0.6% 414/statsd: 0% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 91 minor 19 major
                                                                                                      0.1% 415/netd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 56 minor 1 major
                                                                                                      0.2% 285/keystore2: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 44 minor 5 major
                                                                                                      0.4% 308/jbd2/dm-33-8: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
                                                                                                      0% 519/drmserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 43 minor 2 major
                                                                                                      0.4% 9157/logcat: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
                                                                                                      0.3% 13/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                                                                      0.3% 24/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                                                                      0.3% 42/ksoftirqd/4: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                                                                      0.1% 48/ksoftirqd/5: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                      0% 277/vold: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 23 minor
                                                                                                      0.1% 575/media.metrics: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 33 minor
                                                                                                      0.3% 7114/transport: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                                                                      0.3% 7370/com.google.android.apps.youtube.music: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 8 minor
                                                                                                      0.3% 8578/kworker/u13:2-hci0: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                                                                      0.1% 19/kworker/0:1-virtio_vsock: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                      0.1% 30/ksoftirqd/2: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                      0.1% 171/kworker/2:2-mm_percpu_wq: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                      0.1% 263/lmkd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                      0% 284/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor 1 major
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (9112) for package com.example.rawis ----------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not call `bluetoothSocket.connect()` from your Main/UI thread. You must use a different thread. Otherwise, it will block your UI, and the app will crash.
Please consider using [kotlin Coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines) to create a [CoroutineScope](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) and wrap your connection code in it.

Here's a pattern that you can follow.

1. First, make the `connectToBluetoothDevice` a `suspend` function:

```kotlin
    private suspend fun connectToBluetoothDevice()
```

2. Call this function from a `CoroutineScope`:

```kotlin
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        connectToBluetoothDevice()
    }
```

Comment: Could you be more specific as to how I should modify my code since I am new to this?